# Why it shows two arrays rather than one array

Tags: c, arraylist

I am a beginner of c. Today when i write a c program, I find some strange thing.
What i want it to show is `abc`, but it show `abcefg`. I want to know why it's so shown. 
the code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  char a[3] = "abc";
  char b[3] = "efg";
  printf("%s", a);
  return 0;
}
```

It's answer is not `abc` but `abcefg`

Comment: Typical beginner error: `"abc"` takes 4 bytes! You do not have proper nul-terminated strings in your arrays.

Comment: The answer is found in any beginner-level C book, string chapter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings in C are zero terminated with `'\0'`. `"abc"` actually is `{ 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' }`, which is 4 `char`s. Your array `a` only has room for 3 `char`s so the `'\0'` isn't stored. When `printf()` tries to print the string stored in `a` it reads and prints one character a time until it encounters a terminating `'\0'`, but there is none. So it continues reading and printing. And it happens that `b` is right next to `a` in memory, so the content of `b` gets printet as well.

Cure:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char a[4] = "abc";
    char b[4] = "efg";
    printf("%s", a);
}
```

or, even better, don't specify a size for the arrays at all. Let the compiler figure out the correct size based on the initializer `"abc"`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char a[] = "abc";
    char b[] = "efg";
    printf("%s", a);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`char a[3] = "abc";` misses space for the 0-terminator, so `printf` will read out of bounds (undefined behavior) into the next memory location , where it finds the `b` array (by luck).

You should use `char a[4] = "abc";` or `char a[] = "abc";`.

When you do not write an array size, the compiler will evaluate the minimum size from the initialization.

`char b[3] = "efg";` has the same problem, but it seems that you are lucky enough to have a `0` byte afterwards.